# Getting undefined when declaring a variable in inspect element

Tags: javascript

when i execute the below code in inspect element i get undefined
`Input : var s ='5';`
O/p :  undefined

`console.log(typeof(s))`
Output: string
undefined

Why am i getting undefined after string. I cannot understand the logic why undefined appears all the time when using inspect elemet

Comment: the `console.log` outputs "string" ... in the console you **also** see the returned value of `console.log`, which is undefined, as console.log function returns no value

Answer (score 1):

That's what the call to `console.log` returns. It's used only for *side-effects*, so returns `undefined`.